# Spotfire show both percentage and value in the bar chart?

Tags: bar-chart, percentage, spotfire

In Spotfire is there a way we can show both the value and the percentage in the bar?

Comment: These would be different values on the value axis. So yes, but you'll have to make it a combination chart (line and bar) or side by side / stacked bar so that the value axis can have two different ranges.

Comment: @scsimon this should be an answer! :)

Comment: Ha, fair enough @niko

Answer (score 2):

These would be different values on the value axis. So yes, but you'll have to make it a combination chart (line and bar) or side by side / stacked bar so that the value axis can have two different ranges.

I'd suggest having the value axis split on the left and right as well for readability.

Comment: seems like we cannot have multiple scales for stacked bar chart as combination chart.